# How to omit index.php in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Is there any possibility to omit the index.php in Wordpress? My projects works using only pages (page.php) and I'm using Lingotek for having multiples languages.

1. If I type *http://project/en/* should display the Front Page but it doesn't display anything. **(I want to fix this)**
2. If I type *http://project/* goes directly to *http://project/en/home*

My idea it was to redirect through index.php directly to the Front Page. What would you do?

Comment: Try redirecting the page with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

in your index.php you can call your page 'home':

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php $query = new WP_Query('pagename=home'); if ( $query->have_posts() ) { while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_content();?>

    <?php } } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```